# Download large files without blocking

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm working on Spring Boot application, and I have problems downloading large files. Namely, when I click on download link in client page, it takes a long time for the browser download dialog to appear. For small files, it appears instantly, but for large ones, it takes up to 30 seconds.

This makes me think that my controller blocks until file content is completely written into response output stream before being sent to client. I tried various options to have it send the response immediately, but still have no results. This is what I have so far:

```
 @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/content/file/download")
public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> downloadFile(@RequestParam(name = "path") String path, HttpServletRequest request) 
            throws IOException, NotFoundException, BadRequestException, InternalServerErrorException{
    getApplicationId(request);
    String orgId = getOrganizationId(request);
    LOGGER.debug("Downloading for path {}", path);

    try{
        Session session = getCurrentSession(request);
        FileStorageService service = new JCRFileStorageService(session);
        ProtonItem item = service.getItem(path, orgId);

        InputStream is = service.getFileDownloadStream(path, orgId);
        InputStreamResource resource = new InputStreamResource(is);

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentLength(item.getMetadata().getMetadata(ProtonBaseConstants.META_FILE_SIZE, Long.class));
        headers.set(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, item.getMetadata().getMetadata(ProtonBaseConstants.META_MIME_TYPE, String.class));
        headers.set(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=" + item.getName());

        return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(headers).body(resource);


    }  catch(ProtonRepoException ex){
        throw ProtonExceptionMapper.processException(ex);
    }
}
```

Various sources online point that this should be sufficient to have download start immediately, but it doesn't work. I tried using `IOUtils.copy()`, direct copying from input to output stream, but nothing seems to work.

Is there something I'm missing? Maybe some Spring Boot config, or anything else?

Comment: And what is `service.getFileDownloadStream` doing... Reading something in-memory as a `byte[]` perhaps? Instead of guessing you might want to add metrics to your application to figure out what is taking a long time.

Comment: No, this method just returns `InputStream` to the underlying file. I did check this and it is not the problem, it takes only a few miliseconds to complete.

Comment: How do you create large files? e.g SQL result set mapping to object and then to file, if this is the case then skip mapping and stream from result set directly.

Comment: The files come from Jackrabbit repository. Input stream is obtained as a property of Jackrabbit node. But, as I said, I don't think this is the problem. I measured how long this method takes to execute, and it's only a few miliseconds. The problem is actually at writing data to response output stream.

Answer (score 0):

Use byte[] instead of InputStreamResource, follow this link .. it worked for me in one of my previous project. It should work for you.

http://www.benashby.com/spring/2013/10/30/serving-large-files-spring-mvc.html

Comment: I've already found this article and tried it, but it does not work either.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question... It turns out that problem was not on server side at all, but rather on client. I tested with two different clients, and download works as expected, ie. starts instantly.

The original problem is coming from Angular client we're using and has nothing to do with server side.

Sorry for wasting everybody's time. Thanks a lot for trying to help, guys.

Comment: I don't understand this answer. What are these clients you tested? This seems more like a comment than an answer.

Comment: We use Angular app as a front end. It is downloading file by using GET request to server. The problem, this is not the same as browser GET, ie. browser download window does not show up until file is completely downloaded.